# Custom JavaScript using dynamic data

Tags: javascript, next.js, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to set ecommerce events on our web-site with GTM. And I'm trying to make custom value with custom JavaScript but it continuously shows `undefined`

First, I found data script on our website

```
<script id="__NEXT_DATA__" type="application/json">
```

And I write custom javascript code like below

```
function() {
  var productInfo = [{
    'id':window.__NEXT_DATA__.props.pageProps.program.products[0].id,
    'name':window.__NEXT_DATA__.props.pageProps.program.products[0].name,
    'price':window.__NEXT_DATA__.props.pageProps.program.products[0].price,
    'category':'exhibition'
  }];

  return productInfo;
}
```

Our website is developed with next.js, is it impossible to use script data(?) in custom JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, `__NEXT_DATA__`  is loaded asynchronously. Depends on how you setup GTM. It is possible you are running into a race condition where GTM script runs your custom JavaScript function while Next.js is loading the data.

I think a better approach will be:

1. set up a trigger, which listens to a custom event, in GTM.
2. set up a Tag, which is triggered by the trigger we just setup, in GTM.
3. In your Next.js app, send a custom event when your app is ready. I suggest running the logic in `useEffect` hook.
4. If set up correctly, you will run your custom JavaScript after your app is loaded, which can solve the race condition.